# how to get distinct records in dropdownlistfor form database in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, distinct-values

I am populating a dropdownlist from database. Table has some duplicate records in it. I want the dropdownlist to have distinct results. I have tried following code.

```
model.Specialization = _SpecializationRepository.GetAll().Distinct().Select(x =>
    new SelectListItem
    {
       Value = x.SpecializationId.ToString(),
       Text = x.Description
    });
```

Its taking all the rows from database and displaying it in dropdownlist.

Comment: what about distinct(l = >l.somevalue)

Comment: it's not taking any value

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Comment: Its giving me this error.....Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>' because it is not a delegate type